# Sum paths in weighed graph

Tags: gremlin

I have a bi-directional graph, similar to this: https://gremlify.com/6zxjsbstb5f, where out edges have a weighted property.
There is a closeness relationship between `articles`, the `weight` total of all paths between 2 `articles`

So far I've been able to get the paths between articles, but the weighting is only the `weight` value of the unique path. I would like the aggregate (sum) `weight` of all paths between the starting `article` from the set returned by: `repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).until(hasLabel('article'))`

```java
g.V('70679').
  repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).
  until(hasLabel('article')).as('a').
  path().as('p').
  map(unfold().coalesce(values('weight'),constant(0)).sum()).as('weighting').
  select('weighting', 'p')
```

Steps to create the sample graph (taken from Gremlify)

```java
g.addV('article').as('1').
  addV('brand').as('2').
  addV('article').as('3').
  addV('category').as('4').
  addV('zone').as('5').
  addV('article').as('6').
  addV('article').as('7').
  addE('zone').from('1').to('5').  property('weight', 0.1).
  addE('category').from('1').to('4').property('weight', 0.5).
  addE('brand').from('1').to('2').property('weight', 0.8).
  addE('article').from('2').to('6').
  addE('article').from('2').to('1').
  addE('article').from('2').to('3').  
  addE('zone').from('3').to('5').property('weight', 0.1).  
  addE('category').from('3').to('4').property('weight', 0.3).
  addE('brand').from('3').to('2').property('weight', 0.4).
  addE('article').from('4').to('1').
  addE('article').from('4').to('3').
  addE('article').from('5').to('6').
  addE('article').from('5').to('7').
  addE('article').from('5').to('1').
  addE('article').from('5').to('3').
  addE('zone').from('6').to('5').property('weight', 0.1).
  addE('brand').from('6').to('2').property('weight', 0.6).
  addE('zone').from('7').to('5').property('weight', 0.1)
```

I've been able to get this query which is close to what we require, where `8630` is an article Id in the graph

```java
g.V('8630')
    .repeat(outE().inV().simplePath())
    .until(hasLabel('article')).as('foundArticle')
    .path()
    .map(unfold().coalesce(values('weight'), constant(0)).sum()).as('pathWeight')
    .group().by(select('foundArticle').id()).as('grouping')
```

This produces results similar to:

```java
[
  {
    "8634": [0.1, 0.5, 0.8]
  },
  {
    "8640": [0.1, 0.8]
  },
  {
    "8642": [0.1]
  }
]
```

More desirable would be a result set similar to:

```java
[
  {
    "8634": 1.4
  },
  {
    "8640": 0.9
  },
  {
    "8642": 0.1
  }
]
```

Comment: Are the tags [tag:graphdb] (for "Ontotext GraphDB") and [tag:cosmos] (for the Cosmos OS construction kit) really what you use/mean?

Comment: I removed [tag:cosmos] and [tag:graphdb] - please be sure to add the correct database tag (if this is indeed related to a specific database engine). Note that the [tag:cosmos] tag's description specifically states that it's unrelated to Cosmos DB. If this question is about Cosmos DB, then you'll need to use the correct [tag:azure-cosmosdb] tag.

Comment: I added the steps from Gremlify that create the sample graph to your question. This will allow people to provide tested answers more easily.

Comment: Can you please clarify which vertex represents 70679, as when I look at the Gremlify link, I don't see any vertex with that ID.

Comment: Can you also please update the question to show the exact output you are trying to achieve? Is it just the total weight of all paths found from a starting article to any other article?

Comment: Vertex `70679` is just an `article` vertex. It seems when the graph is exported/imported the `ids` are not preserved.
The query I'm looking for will start at any arbitrary `article` vertex and explore paths to other `article` vertices, ranking and grouping the discovered `article` and path weight sum.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the desired result?

Comment: Ideally a tuple containing the found `article` vertex and the sum of all path weight's from the starting vertex to the found `article` vertex. e.g.
Assume starting at vertex '1' result similar to:
[ {'3', 0.8 }, { '6', 0.5 }, { '7', 0.1 } ] 
Sum of paths to article '3'  = 0.1 + 0.3 + 0.4
Sum of paths to article '6' = 0.1 + 0.4
Sum of paths to article '7' = 0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it easier I gave each article a custom ID. The ID `A1` corresponds to the example output you showed for ID `8630`.

```java
g.addV('article').as('1').property(id,'A1').
  addV('brand').as('2').
  addV('article').as('3').property(id,'A2').
  addV('category').as('4').
  addV('zone').as('5').
  addV('article').as('6').property(id,'A3').
  addV('article').as('7').property(id,'A4').
  addE('zone').from('1').to('5').  property('weight', 0.1).
  addE('category').from('1').to('4').property('weight', 0.5).
  addE('brand').from('1').to('2').property('weight', 0.8).
  addE('article').from('2').to('6').
  addE('article').from('2').to('1').
  addE('article').from('2').to('3').  
  addE('zone').from('3').to('5').property('weight', 0.1).  
  addE('category').from('3').to('4').property('weight', 0.3).
  addE('brand').from('3').to('2').property('weight', 0.4).
  addE('article').from('4').to('1').
  addE('article').from('4').to('3').
  addE('article').from('5').to('6').
  addE('article').from('5').to('7').
  addE('article').from('5').to('1').
  addE('article').from('5').to('3').
  addE('zone').from('6').to('5').property('weight', 0.1).
  addE('brand').from('6').to('2').property('weight', 0.6).
  addE('zone').from('7').to('5').property('weight', 0.1)
```

The query you had produced, was actually very close to having the result you wanted. I just added a second `by` step to the `group` to sum up the values.

```java
g.V('A1').
  repeat(outE().inV().simplePath()).
  until(hasLabel('article')).as('foundArticle').
  path().
  map(unfold().coalesce(values('weight'), constant(0)).sum()).as('pathWeight').
  group().
    by(select('foundArticle').id()).
    by(sum()).
  unfold()
```

Which yields

```
{'A2': 1.4}
{'A3': 0.9}
{'A4': 0.1}
```

I think your query can also be simplified. If I come up with something simpler I will add it to this answer,

**UPDATED**

Here's a version of the query that uses `sack` and avoids needing to collect the `path` and post process it.

```java
g.withSack(0).
  V('A1').
  repeat(outE().sack(sum).by(coalesce(values('weight'),constant(0))).
         inV().simplePath()).
  until(hasLabel('article')).
  group().
    by(id()).
    by(sack().sum()).
  unfold()
```

which again yields

```
{'A2': 1.4}
{'A3': 0.9}
{'A4': 0.1}
```

Comment: Is it possible to order by the group sum value?

Comment: Yes, just add `order().by(values)` to my example.

Comment: That seems to be ordering by the `id` value, not the group sum value.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what you want to order by. `values` will be the floating point numbers.

Comment: Thanks, just re-ran the query on my full graph and its working as expected. PEBKAC